# How can I get "Plane.000" instead of "Plane"?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

Obviously it doesn't seem to be a problem for too many people, but to me it is simply looking wrong each time I see it.

In my opinion the first object should be called **Plane.000** here automatically when every subsequent item is **Plane.00x** anyway.

[image]

And here the next plane should obviously be **Plane.002** and not **Plane**.

[image]

Can I somewhere change Blender's behavior here?? (It is really looking very wrong to me...)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this sounds like a feature request, not a question.

Comment: "Can I somewhere change Blender's behavior here?"

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos it is however a pretty simply implemented "feature" with python.  Maybe editing q to make it sound like less of a feature request.... or less critical of blender to avoid DV's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend doing this, BUT here is a way to change blenders default naming behaviour.  The following needs to be "tightened up" for other names eg will make mistakes with names like "Planet", but will do as a simple example.

Open a new blender file, run the script below, then add or duplicate planes.  The `scene_update_pre` handler runs alot.  Any added plane, cube or sphere will be renamed to start at 000.

```
import bpy
prim_names = ["Plane", "Cube", "Sphere"]

def name_prims(scene):
    for name in prim_names:
        prims = [o for o in bpy.data.objects 
                 if o.name.startswith(name)]
        newprim = scene.objects.get(name)
        if newprim:
            newprim.name = "%s.%03d" % (name, len(prims) - 1)

# make it a handler
bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.append(name_prims)
```

Remove all scene update pre handlers with: (Note this will remove all handlers, this one and those added by addons, etc)

```
# remove all handlers
bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.clear()
```

Otherwise remove it by name

```
my_handlers = [h for h in bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre
               if h.__name__.startswith("name_prims")]

for h in my_handlers:
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.remove(h)
```

Comment: That's great. I will have a look at it. Thanks. What's your reason to not recommend it?

Comment: It's ok I suppose to run while adding lots of planes (etc) and to get the different naming convention.  The handler runs a lot of time.  to make code foolproof would have to add more tests, and more overhead.  Note I edited a bit, one to look at all prims in data, and to include other prim names.

Comment: Blender is smart when it comes to giving objects a name and even this works: https://pastebin.com/005DynYX . Is there something I can do to add such a handler to a Startup file?

Comment: Give the file in text editor a .py extension and click the register checkbox and it will run when file is opened.   Could add to start up file like so... and make handler persistent. [Handlers](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html)